# Translating PHP date() for Multilingual Site

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to create a conditional translation of the PHP internal date() function.  Is it possible to somehow redefine the internal variables - e.g. - date('M'), date('y') etc so that different strings are fed into the remainder of the PHP function on the basis of this test:

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') { }
```

The following is a working example of the code I'm using for a dates module.  Since `$date` is defined with many variables contained in this definition it's important to conditionally re-define the variables within PHP's `date()` first in order to avoid having to redefine the variable 100 times or more within each key.

```
if($start <= $end):
    if($start == $end):
        //Month Day, Year
        $date =  date('F', $start).' '.date('j',$start).', '.date('Y', $start);
    else:
        if($start_year == $end_year):
            if($start_month == $end_month):

                //Month Day - Day, Year
                $date = date('F', $start).' '.date('j',$start).' - '.date('j', $end).', '.date('Y', $start);
            else:
                //Month Day - Month Day, Year
                $date =  date('F', $start).' '.date('j',$start).' - '.date('F', $end).' '.date('j', $end).', '.date('Y', $start);
            endif;
        else:
            //Month Day, Year - Month Day, Year
            $date =  date('F', $start).' '.date('j',$start).', '.date('Y', $start).' - '.date('F', $end).' '.date('j', $end).', '.date('Y', $end);
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Whenever you need to manipulate date/time stamps based on locale, you should use [strftime](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax):

```
switch ($lang) {
    case 'en':
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_CA.UTF-8');
        echo strftime("%B %e, %G");
        break;
    case 'fr':
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
        echo strftime("%e %B %G");
        break;
}
```

Results:

```
February 11, 2011  // en
11 février 2011    // fr
```

Of course, you need to have the locales installed on your system. In Ubuntu per example:

```
bash-4.1$ sudo locale-gen fr_CA.UTF-8
```

> EDIT in may 2022

`strftime()` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0

This is how you should do it:

```
$fmt = datefmt_create(
    'pt_BR', // The output language.
    pattern: "cccc, d 'de' LLLL 'de' YYYY" // The output formatting.
);
$input = strtotime(date('d-m-Y'));
$output = datefmt_format($fmt, $input);

var_dump($output); // Outputs "segunda-feira, 20 de junho de 2022".
```

As for `strtotime()` use:

- slash (/) for American M/D/Y formatting;
- dash (-) for European D-M-Y formatting and
- period (.) for ISO Y.M.D formatting.

In my sample I am using the european day-month-year formatting.

[Click here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax) to see how to format the value of `$pattern` parameter in `datefmt_create()`.

You must have the intl package installed:

```
$ sudo apt install php8.1-intl
```

Change the `8.1` bit to the php version you are working with.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. Using `date()` falls apart when you try to use it for anything but numeric values.

Comment: Awesome ... thank you. Both for answering the question and details on how to install a new locale

Comment: How can you  know the order where will be the %e %B %G according to the locales

Comment: strftime has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0

Answer (score 8):

```
    $date =  date('F', $start).' '.date('j',$start).', '.date('Y', $start);
```

That's a rather painful way to go about. The format string in `date()` doesn't have to be a single character. This line could be reduced to

```
$date = date('F j Y');
```

And given that, you could have a simple

```
switch($whats_my_locale) {
    case 'FR':
       $format = 'date format characters for a french date';
       break
    case 'EN' :
       $format = 'format chars for english date'
       break
    case etc....
    default:
       $format = 'default date format string here';
}

$local_date_string = date($format, $start);
```

and off you go.

Comment: This looks great, my question is - in the context of `$format = 'date format characters... fr';` how are these variables (e.g. 'm', 'd', 'M') etc. being re-defined to French?

Comment: And my apologies for being dense! :(

Comment: The `date()` man page (http://php.net/date) says to use `setlocale()` and `strftime()` for non-english dates. But the same format string rules basically apply there - it doesn't have to be a single char, it can be a string of formatting chars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have, but have you considered just using the numeric values?

Also, if you do use them, remember the US has months / day, opposite to the UK and others.

Comment: That's a thought.  I definitely hope to avoid this but it did escape me... I'll count this as a backup plan.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it is nicer to have a full date, but users would definitely prefer a functional numeric one. Heck, you could even just use a random javascript date.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this lately and I found out a way to translate datetime in php.

Let's take the fr example

- First I created a new Class that extend GlobalDateTime

in `App\Core\DateTime.php`

```php
    namespace App\Core;
    
    use DateTime as GlobalDateTime;
    
    class DateTime extends GlobalDateTime
    {
        public function __construct($str_date = "now")
        {
            parent::__construct($str_date);
        }
    
        public function toLocalTimeString(): string
        {
            $Y = $this->format('Y');
            $M = $this->_get('month', $this->format('m'));
            $l = $this->_get('day', $this->format('l'));
            $d = $this->format('d');
            $H = $this->format('H');
            $i = $this->format('i');
    
            return "$l $d $M $Y à $H:$i";
        }
    
        private function _get($key, $id): string
        {
            return [
                'day' => [
                    0 => "Dim",
                    1 => "Lun",
                    2 => "Mar",
                    3 => "Mer",
                    4 => "Jeu",
                    5 => "Ven",
                    6 => "Sam",
                    "Sun" => "Dim",
                    "Mon" => "Lun",
                    "Tue" => "Mar",
                    "Wed" => "Mer",
                    "Thu" => "Jeu",
                    "Fri" => "Ven",
                    "Sat" => "Sam",
                    "Sunday" => "Dimanche",
                    "Monday" => "Lundi",
                    "Tuesday" => "Mardi",
                    "Wednesday" => "Mercredi",
                    "Thursday" => "Jeudi",
                    "Friday" => "Vendredi",
                    "Saturday" => "Samedi",
                ],
                'month' => [
                    "01" => "Jan",
                    "02" => "Fév",
                    "03" => "Mar",
                    "04" => "Avr",
                    "05" => "Mai",
                    "06" => "Juin",
                    "07" => "Juil",
                    "08" => "Aôut",
                    "09" => "Sept",
                    "10" => "Oct",
                    "11" => "Nov",
                    "12" => "Déc",
                ],
            ][$key][$id];
        }
    }
```

- And then I can call it wherever I want like

```php
use App\Core\DateTime;

$datetime = new DateTime('now');
$strdatetime = $datetime->toLocalTimeString(); // return vendredi 18 Aôut 2022 à 08:00
```

- You can custom this DateTime class as you like

I hope this will help you.