# Php multilanguage date: howto?

Tags: php, datetime, translation

Nota: this is not a duplicate of [Translating PHP date() for Multilingual Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975854/translating-php-date-for-multilingual-site) . I've read it!

I'm sorry, I first have to explain how my framework works, so you can understand precisely where my problem is:

Here's how my Php code works (rough principles). Let's use for an example someone who wants to see the URL `http://myweb.com/valid.php`:

- in the file `valid.php` the code include the right classes definition then create one object and call the function `display()` which displays the page.
- in the file `valid.php`, when the object is created, it analyses the host, and in the host there's the language (`http://`**`us`**`.myweb.com/`, `http://`**`cn`**`.myweb.com/`, `http://`**`fr`**`.myweb.com/`...) and the default language (if none found) is english
- then I load a cached Php file where the are the translations. This is a `translation` object, that I'm calling **`$t`** for short
- and from now on, whenever I want a translation, I just do things like `$t->get('my_string')`.

Let's take an example with 2 languages file:

- 2 languages files: `cache.us.php` and `cache.fr.php`
- in `cache.us.php` you have a line like this: `$thanks_for_the_fish = "Thanks for the fish"`.
- in `cache.fr.php` you have a line like this: `$thanks_for_the_fish = "Merci pour le poisson"`.
- I construct my page, include the right language file then call `$t->get('thanks_for_the_fish')` and it's translated.

Now my problem comes with date formatting.
With short date format it's not a problem:

- in `cache.us.php`: `$short_date_format = "m/d/Y, H:i"`.
- in `cache.fr.php`: `$short_date_format = "d/m/Y à H:i"`.

But with **long** date format, I'm just working on french and I begun with something like:

- in `cache.fr.php`: `$long_date_format = "%s, %d %s %d"`.
- then all the days: `$sunday = "dimanche"`, `$monday = "lundi"` and so on
- then in my translation code:

Something like this (read carefully the comment in the code, my question is in it!):

```
static private $_TabStrDaysOfWeek = array(
    0 => 'sunday',
    1 => 'monday',
    ...,
    6 => 'saturday'
);
public function translateDate($date_time)
{
    $long_day = $this->tr->get(
        $this->_TabStrDaysOfWeek[ $date_time->format('w') ]
    );
    /*

    here's where I'm stuck:
    what could be the code to be able to display:
    - english:
      Monday, 1st September 2006
      Tuesday, 2nd September 2006
      Wednesday, 3rd September 2006
      Thursday, 4th September 2006

    - french:
      Lundi, 1 septembre 2006
      Mardi, 2 septembre 2006
      Mercredi, 3 septembre 2006
      Jeudi, 4 septembre 2006

    - arabian!!:
      1 - Don't know
      2 - Don't know
      3 - Don't know
      4 - Don't know
    */
}
```

... And I said arabian because I'll need it sooner or later, same for Mandarin Chinese.
All my other translation problems are solved but this one!!

Any idea?

Comment: You should keep weekday names separate and translated and put them in long date string. Something like `$french_monday.', 1 septembre 2006';`

Comment: If so, how would you do with english? Arabian? Mandarin chinese?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a bit of a hurry, so maybe I skipped some important part, but is there a reason not to use the PHP `intl` extension? The [IntlDateFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestion could be a valid option, may I ask you to write a detailed answer so that I can check it as valid, to help the community? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For internationalization tasks, I'd strongly recommend using the PHP [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) extension. It contains several classes for common internationalization tasks such as date/time formatting, number formatting, string transliteration and more. Specifically, the [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class
is able to format (and parse) a datetime for any available locale.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've installed this extension and I'll modify my multilanguage class to use this incredibly powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it: it seems there's no possibility other than do a switch and handle each language separately:

---

Here's what's in my cache:

```
$this->jour_dimanche = dimanche
$this->jour_lundi = lundi
$this->jour_mardi = mardi
$this->jour_mercredi = mercredi
$this->jour_jeudi = jeudi
$this->jour_vendredi = vendredi
$this->jour_samedi = samedi

$this->mois_janvier = janvier
$this->mois_fevrier = février
$this->mois_mars = mars
$this->mois_avril = avril
$this->mois_mai = mai
$this->mois_juin = juin
$this->mois_juillet = juillet
$this->mois_aout = août
$this->mois_septembre = septembre
$this->mois_octobre = octobre
$this->mois_novembre = novembre
$this->mois_decembre = décembre

// long date format = 'day, (month number) (month) (year)'
// '%s, %d %s %d' => 'Mardi, 2 juillet 2012'
$this->date_format_long = %\s, j %\s Y à H:i
```

...And my Php code:

```
public function translateDate($date_time, $first_upcase=true)
{   
    switch ($this->_trad->getLang()) {
        /* TODO: all other languages */
        case 'us':
        case 'ar':
        case 'es':
        case 'cn':
            throw new Exception("not handled yet");
            break;

        default:
            /* default = french */
            $day = $this->_trad->get(
                self::$_TabStrDaysOfWeek[ $date_time->format('w') ]
            );  
            $month = $this->_trad->get(
                self::$_TabStrMonths[ $date_time->format('j') ]
            );  
            $ret = sprintf(
                $date_time->format(
                    $this->_trad->get('date_format_long')
                ),  
                $day,
                $month
            );  
            if ($first_upcase) {
                $ret = ucfirst($ret);
            }   
            break;
    }   
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for you, check it out maybe it help you
https://github.com/LeonardoCaitano/MyDateTime