# Output of date/time in German in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, language-translation

Got a bit of an odd question. After creating a PHP script for a friend who lives in Germany, he has decided he needs the time/date in German format, an example being:

Montag, 16.März 2014

Is there a date/time function that can do this in PHP?

Any help much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Would this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11333780/825114?

Comment: If you check date() manual you could format the date as you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 4):

Use [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and set the locale to German

---

**Example**

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
    echo strftime("%A, %e.%B %Y"); 
?>
```

Which would output: `Donnerstag,  7.August 2014`

Comment: Be careful while using LC_ALL , read this comment i faced same issue
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#25041

Comment: use LC_TIME instead of LC_ALL