# Set language of DateTime in symfony2

Tags: symfony-forms

Is there a way to have Symfony2 translate the months within a Form?

Now I have a select with the month`s shortcut in english, I would like to have it in spanish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but this may help others stumbling on this post.

I think this is not related to Symfony2 itself, but what you may want to do is set the correct locale in PHP.
See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4976419

If you have the Spanish locale on your system, `setLocale` will do the trick.

Beware, though, that [`date()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is not locale-aware. As seen in the post above, you should use [`strftime()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead.