# How can I translate date in php?

Tags: php, date, translate

I want to translate dates into french. 
For exemple I have `Thursday 15 September 2016` and I want to have `Jeudi 15 Septembre 2016`

My date is in dateTime format : `2016-07-20 10:51:00`

I tried to do this :

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR','fra');

echo strftime('%A %d %B %Y);
```

But it doesn't work for me. I have the date in english.

Comment: setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR'); Try getting rid of the third parameter

Comment: Try checking the return value from `setlocale()`

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, It doesn't change anything...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php setlocale has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect)

Comment: When I do `echo setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');` I don't have return

Comment: Basically all the solutions are useless if you do not have the french locale installed on your server.

Comment: I tried to do this : `apt-get install locales`but it tell me that I have already intalled this

Comment: Well there are multiple solutions on the question I linked that are better than the duplicate non-working answers you are getting here - just work through them.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, I tried all solution you give me but it doesn't working

Comment: @wxcvbn - you will have a return, but it;'s likely to be a __boolean__ `false`, which doesn't display anything when echoed; var_dump it rather than simply trying to echo it.... learn to debug

Comment: @MarkBaker, In fact, now I have `bool(false)`. What does it mean?

Comment: As per the [PHP Docs for setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), `Returns... FALSE if the locale functionality is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not exist or the category name is invalid.`... have a look at the link in @Anthony's comment to see how to check/install locales

Comment: @MarkBaker, I read @Anthony's link. When I do `locale -a` I remark I don't have fr_FR. So do `locale-gen fr_FR`and after `update-locale`. But after whe I do `locale -a`anything change...

Comment: Some how the duplicate flag was "disputed", even though this question is the same as the one I linked!

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, I look at your link. It the solution, I don't have fr_FR.utf8 into locale. I tried to add this but it doesn't work

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, It' ok it's working now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try This..!

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
echo (strftime("%A %d %B %Y"));
```

Comment: This would return " in French 15.59.2016 and"

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, In fact I have the same result

Comment: change date & check

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %G");
```

Next time try to google your question.
[Translating PHP date() for Multilingual Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975854/translating-php-date-for-multilingual-site)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the return value of setlocale, because it will fail if the locale string is invalid, the locale you want is not installed, or some other reason

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL) {
    echo("Unable to set locale");
}
```

You can check what locales are available with `locale -a`. Maybe you do have a French locale installed, but you have to set it with `fr_FR.utf8`.

or

try this,

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%A %e %B %G");
```

or

try this,

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%A %B %e, %Y', strtotime('2016-09-15 11:21:53')));// your date
```

**[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)**

Comment: I have date in english : `Thursday 15 September 2016``

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show the date store in DB in different format and in Greek language.
I post this to save some time for people that searching same problem solution.
Use this function to replace the date string from DB with your target language. Replace the Greek days and months strings.
If you need another date format you need to change date_format param following directions from  https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_date_date.asp

```
function TranslateDate($stringDate) {  
$MonthGR = array('Ιανουάριου', 'Φεβρουάριου', 'Μάρτιου', 'Απρίλιου', 'Μάϊου', 'Ιούνιου', 'Ιούλιου', 'Αυγούστου', 'Σεπτεμβρίου', 'Οκτωβρίου', 'Νοεμβρίου', 'Δεκεμβρίου');
$MonthEN = array('/January/', '/February/', '/March/', '/April/', '/May/', '/June/', '/July/', '/August/', '/September/', '/October/', '/November/', '/December/');

$DayGR = array('Δευτέρα', 'Τρίτη', 'Τετάρτη', 'Πέμπτη', 'Παρασκευή', 'Σάββατο', 'Κυριακή');
$DayEN = array('/Monday/', '/Tuesday/', '/Wednesday/', '/Thursday/', '/Friday/', '/Saturday/', '/Sunday/');

$hmera = preg_replace($MonthEN, $MonthGR, date_format(date_create($stringDate), 'l d F Y G:i '));
$hmera = preg_replace($DayEN, $DayGR, $hmera);

return $hmera;}
```