# spanish output for "date" function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

i want to echo cMonth in spanish.. i was trying differents things without result. any idea?

```
if($_REQUEST["month"]>0){
    $cMonth = "0".intval($_REQUEST["month"]);
    if ($_REQUEST["month"]>9) {
        $cMonth = intval($_REQUEST["month"]);
    }
    $cYear = intval($_REQUEST["year"]);
}else
{
    $cMonth = date("m");
    $cYear = date("Y");
}

echo date("F, Y",strtotime($cYear."-".$cMonth."-01"));
```

Comment: Use strftime (http://php.net/strftime) instead of "date". Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975854/translating-php-date-for-multilingual-site

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use this methode Just

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
    $string = "27/12/2016";
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $string);
    echo strftime("%B", $date->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: thanks!! but i dont know well how integrated here:
date("F, Y",strtotime($cYear."-".$cMonth."-01"));

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: @CosmicDisco, I guess you want see in this format "F, Y" but using strftime. You could check [strftime documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php).

Comment: the problem is i want the months in spanish.. when i try to modify strtotime for strftime doesnt work. i dont know how to modify this: date("F, Y",strtotime($cYear."-".$cMonth."-01"));

Comment: Try To Modifier your echo date("F, Y", strtotime($cYear . "-" . $cMonth . "-01"));
 by
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
        $string = $cYear . "/" . $cMonth . "/01";
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d", $string);
        echo strftime("%B, %Y", $date->getTimestamp());

The Out Put Its Like What you want